# Java file upload validations best practices

Tags: java, validation, gwt, file-upload, server-side

I am implementing a simple image upload widget in GWT. Before the successful upload, there are some basic validations that needs to be performed, like:

1. Size
2. File type

What is the best place to do this validation?
As per my knowledge, size and type validation can only be done at the server side.
I.e the servlet (MyUploadServlet extends HttpServlet) does the actual upload of file.
Is that the only place? What will be the best practice to do such validations?

Also, if I can get the validation code (image file type and size), that will be great :)

Answer (score 1):

The validation can be better done on server side.
Basically I would recommend you 2 step for size validation:

1) Validate HTTP headers for content-length. request.getContentLength()

2) If headers are not available, then do the actual size validation while reading the input stream. So if you reach the limit you can throw an exception.

On gwt client side you can validate the exception and show the appropriate error.

Determining the file type can be not so straightforward. You can just check file name extension or use file type specific validations after the file is actually uploaded on server.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. What I was more interested in the best practice (in terms of code organization) we should follow to do such validation like there should be a different validator class? or it can be in the same servlet? from where should validation values come from - spring file or somewhere else? Hope I am able to explain this time :)

Comment: If you use spring, you can use spring mvc for upload handling. In spring config you should define a MultipartResolver:           `<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>`                                                               So the spring framework will take care of the validation.

Comment: This is a nice article on the topic http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/

Comment: Thanks Alexey, that will be helpful. Will try this out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 has varied support for the File API which means some browsers will be able to give you the size of files for uploading BEFORE talking to the server.  If you can assume something about the browsers you are using you might want to search for something along the lines of `html 5 file api size` and see if you'll be able to use it in your case.